# Hibernate JPA persist saved child entity with null parent id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities:
parent :

```
public class UserGroup{
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users;
}
```

and child:

```
public class User{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id")  
    private UserGroup userGroup;
}
```

when i am trying to save UserGroup with one User in list of users, with this method:

```
  @Transactional
public E save(E e) {
    em.persist(e);
    em.flush();
    em.refresh(e);
    return e;
}
```

my parent and child is getting saved, but user_group_id in child object is null.
Is there any solution?

Comment: `user_group_id` in child object right?

Comment: user_group_id in child in DB, yes, my mistake

Comment: You have to set `user_group_id` when parent object is `save()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By considering you are giving `UserGroup` object along with list of `User` to save method: so your code should be:

```
em.save(userGroup);
for(User user : UserGroup.getUsers()) 
{
user.setuser_group_id(userGroup.getUserGroupId());
em.save(user);
}
```

Comment: but this kind of breaks the purpose of cascade operation. There should be only 1 call to save that handles both parent and child entities.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bidirectional relationship. The correct way of saving it is putting both references in the entities.

You should do:

```
userGroup.getUsers().add(user);
user.setUserGroup(userGroup);
entityManager.persist(userGroup);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your parent setter method of child, do this.

```
public void setChildren(Collection<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
    for(Child child: this.children) {
      child.setParent(this)
    }
}
```

This should solve.